# Querying mongodb with long values from spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Trying to fetch all the documents that are 20 days old from mongo db

```
@Query("{'$expr': {'$gte': [{'$subtract': [?1, '$createdAt']}, ?0]}}")
List<Model> findAllModelCreatedBefore(long timeDifference, long currentTime);
```

createdAt is a field in the model.

I'm calling the method by

```
modelRepository.findAllModelCreatedBefore(1728000000, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

But getting **org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found '}'.**